# How to organize two functions different in the middle part

Tags: c++

I would like to ask how to nicely organize the below two functions.

I apologize for not uploading the complete code.

```
void prepend_float(t_ptr *x, float f)
{
    int ac = x->num;
    t_atom *av = static_cast<t_atom *>(malloc(sizeof(t_atom) * ac));
    av[0].type = A_FLOAT; //not common
    av[0].f = f;          //not common
    for (int i = 1; i < ac; ++i)
    {
        av[i].type = A_FLOAT;
        av[i].f = x->fv[i - 1];
    }
    do_something(x, ac, av);
    free(av);
}

void prepend_string(t_ptr *x, std::string s)
{
    int ac = x->num;
    t_atom *av = static_cast<t_atom *>(malloc(sizeof(t_atom) * ac));
    av[0].type = A_STRING; //not common
    av[0].s = s;           //not common
    for (int i = 1; i < ac; ++i)
    {
        av[i].type = A_FLOAT;
        av[i].f = x->fv[i - 1];
    }
    do_something(x, ac, av);
    free(av);
}
```

As you can see the two functions have identical code except for the two lines where I marked `not common`.

How can I create a common function to reduce the duplicated code?

What I can think now is to create a common function that has 4 arguments like the following.

```
void common_function(t_ptr *x, float f, std::string, t_type type)
{
    int ac = x->num;
    t_atom *av = static_cast<t_atom *>(malloc(sizeof(t_atom) * ac));
    if (type == A_FLOAT)
    {
        av[0].type = type;
        av[0].f = f;   
    }
    else if (type == A_STRING)
    {
        av[0].type = type;
        av[0].s = s; 
    }       
    for (int i = 1; i < ac; ++i)
    {
        av[i].type = A_FLOAT;
        av[i].f = x->fv[i - 1];
    }
    do_something(x, ac, av);
    free(av);
}
```

Is there a better way to organize the two functions?

Comment: Which compiler (and version thereof) are you working with? Some language features may be available to make this easier/nicer.

Comment: @T2PS `Default compiler (Apple LLVM 9.0)` Language Dialect: `C++14[-std=c++14]` Standard Library : `libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)` Are these enough info?

Comment: Why use `malloc`/`free` in c++ :( ?? Also what if `do_something` throws an exception? You may have a memory leak.

Comment: Instead of passing a `float` and a `std::string` pass a `std::variant`. That might also be the type to choose for t_atom. BTW: Don't use malloc/free, use new/delete. And better: don't use raw pointers, use managed pointers. (Read https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines).

Comment: Extending @PaulRooney: Using `malloc`, you get uninitialised memory, the constructor of the atoms is never called. While it might not impose a problem to your real code, according to the standard, you still invoke undefined behaviour...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options for. Classic way would be encapsulating the common code into functions being called from both functions in question:

```
void f()
{
    common_pre(); // parameters/return value as needed
    specific_f();
    common_post();
}

void g()
{
    common_pre();
    specific_g();
    common_post();
}
```

You could pack the common code into a single function and pass a lambda to as well:

```
template<typename Function>
void common(Function& f) // alternatively, instead of template, std::function
{
    common_pre();
    f();
    common_post();
}

void f()
{
    common([/* capture as needed*/] (/*possibly parameters...*/) { /* f specific code */ });
}

void g()
{
    common([] () { /* g specific code */ });
}
```

The lambda approach is the one I would favour in given case and might look like this:

```
template <typename Function>
void doPrepend(t_ptr* x, Function& f)
{
    int ac = x->num;
    t_atom* av = static_cast<t_atom *>(malloc(sizeof(t_atom) * ac));
    f(av);
    for (int i = 1; i < ac; ++i)
    {
        av[i].type = A_FLOAT;
        av[i].f = x->fv[i - 1];
    }
    do_something(x, ac, av);
    free(av);
}

void prepend_float(t_ptr* x, float f)
{
    auto assign = [f](t_atom* av)
    {
        av->type = A_FLOAT;
        av->f = f;
    };
    doPrepend(x, assign);
}

void prepend_string(t_ptr* x, std::string const& s)
{
    auto assign = [&s](t_atom* av)
    {
        av->type = A_STRING;
        av->s = s;
    };
    doPrepend(x, assign);
}
```

*Edit:* Inspired by [schorsch312](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2416647/schorsch312)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51835046/1312382), however instead of relying on boost and string comparisons, resolving via simple function overload:

```
void assign(t_atom* av, float f)
{
    av->type = A_FLOAT;
    av->f = f;
}

void assign(t_atom* av, std::string const& s)
{
    av->type = A_STRING;
    av->s = s;
}

template <typename T>
void prepend(t_ptr* x, T const& t)
{
    int ac = x->num;
    t_atom* av = static_cast<t_atom *>(malloc(sizeof(t_atom) * ac));
    assign(av, t);
    for (int i = 1; i < ac; ++i)
    {
#if 0
        av[i].type = A_FLOAT;
        av[i].f = x->fv[i - 1];
#else
        // in this approach; we can even re-use the assign function:
        assign(av + i, x->fv[i - 1]);
#endif
    }
    do_something(x, ac, av);
    free(av);
}
```

Even a bit less complex than the lambda approach, although the difference is not too significant.

It results in only one single function name (which you could have achieved in the preceding two approaches by overloading the two functions instead of having separate names), though, possibly imposing further changes (specification, documentation, code already using the interface) on you.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion: Keep the common parts and turn the differences into parameters.

In your case the difference is two statements. That can be abstracted out by using a function. `std::function` lets us handle any callable object, and lambda expressions make it easy to pass an ad-hoc function (consisting of the two type-specific statements we need to execute in the middle of the common code):

```
void prepend_something(t_ptr *x, std::function<void (t_atom &)> init)
{
    int ac = x->num;
    t_atom *av = static_cast<t_atom *>(malloc(sizeof(t_atom) * ac));
    init(av[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < ac; ++i)
    {
        av[i].type = A_FLOAT;
        av[i].f = x->fv[i - 1];
    }
    do_something(x, ac, av);
    free(av);
}

void prepend_float(t_ptr *x, float f)
{
    prepend_something(x, [f](t_atom &a) { a.type = A_FLOAT; a.f = f; });
}

void prepend_string(t_ptr *x, std::string s)
{
    prepend_something(x, [s](t_atom &a) { a.type = A_STRING; a.s = s; });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a template and `boost type_index`.

```
template <typename T>
void prepend_string(t_ptr *x, T s) {
    int ac = x->num;
    t_atom *av = static_cast<t_atom *>(malloc(sizeof(t_atom) * ac));
    const std::string valueType = boost::typeindex::type_id<T>().pretty_name();
    if (valueType == "float") {
       av[0].type = A_FLOAT;
       av[0].f = f;         
    } else if (valueType == "string") {
        av[0].type = A_STRING; 
        av[0].s = s;           
    } else {
         // error handling
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < ac; ++i) {
        av[i].type = A_FLOAT;
        av[i].f = x->fv[i - 1];
    }
    do_something(x, ac, av);
    free(av);
}
```

This works an Linux and windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could use object orientation.

Create an abstract BaseClass and derived classes with type string and float. 
In the av structure you have references to the BaseClass and can access manipulation or get methods of the abstract BaseClass.

```
class MyBaseType
{
     virtual Type GetType() = 0;
     /* manipulation methods .. */
     std::string GetValueAsString() = 0;
}

class MyStringType : public MyBaseType
{
     // implement abstract methods of base class
}
class MyFloatType : public MyBaseType
{
     // implement abstract methods of base class
}

void prepend(t_ptr *x, MyBaseType *MyType)
{
    int ac = x->num;
    t_atom *av = static_cast<t_atom *>(malloc(sizeof(t_atom) * ac));
    av[0] = MyType; 
    for (int i = 1; i < ac; ++i)
    {
        av[i].type = A_FLOAT;
        av[i].f = x->fv[i - 1];
    }
    do_something(x, ac, av);
    free(av);
}
```

Comment: While in general, a nice idea, in given case imposes problems as OP wants to create an array of exactly that type which would be the base type, so we would have to fight with type erasure or would need an array of pointers with each object allocated separately (be aware that in string case, we have one string element followed by further float elements!).

Comment: i updated my comment with a code example. I see that my approach might not be in every case the best solution, depending on the rest of the program architecture.

Comment: Ah, now I see *where* you intended to use the base type... You'd have to change the loop as well, though, as you'd need to assign `MyFloatTypes` to the elements then, too. Danger of memory leaks exists if not using smart pointers for. However, as not POD types, malloc then *absolutely* cannot be used any more. Admitted, not mentioned, so performance likely is not an issue, but *if*, pointer indirection comes with some cost as well.